# CSS Root Path for Windows different with Mac?

Tags: css, path

I just started learning Compass by watching tutorial video. But my question is for general CSS.

Here's how the directory looks like:

```
/root
    /images
        /mySprites.png
    /javascript
    /stylesheets
        /myStyle.css
    index.html
```

When auto-generating sprites, Compass output the path like this:

```
url('/images/mySprites.png');
```

But using Chrome in Windows, that path leads to `stylesheets/images/mysprites.png` and thus not showing up.

He's using Chrome in Mac and the sprites are shown correctly.

I know `/` is used to start from root folder, but is it not working in Windows?

Comment: it wiuld be `../images/mysprites.png`

Comment: Yeah I know. But every time I change something in Compass, the wrong path is re-written back. Is it problem in windows or browser?

Comment: If the path is what you have written above, it is completely correct.  Have you tried removing your browser cache and looking at source code to make sure the "/" is there?

Comment: I have checked the source code and the `/` is there. Clearing cache doesn't work, it also have same problem in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` in the first is not one of the CSS rules if some browsers understand that you are pointing to the root folder, they are doing it on their own and there is no such thing in CSS. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri

So, the best way is to enter paths relative to the CSS file, not the document root or enter full URL like this: `http://example.com/images/mySprite.png`

All the best wishes,
[Mohammad Ali Sharpasand](http://m.a.sharpasand.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I though that's native rule in css

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, just use "**...**/images/mysprites.png" as that will instruct the CSS to look one level above it's containing folder.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thanks. But as stated above, the path resets back every time the compass compiles. I think this is a bug on Ruby for Windows 8

Comment: Potentially this may be your answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393161/sass-compass-path-in-config-rb-causing-problem-on-compile